# Setting up a WxWidgets project on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

Has anybody succeeded in compiling a WxWidgets-3.1.1 demo project on eclipse? I am using the MinGW-64 toolchain, and using the included makefiles projects build just fine.

Unfortunately when I set-up a project using eclipse CDT, I end up in an endless sequence of linker errors, mostly related to windows libraries. I added all the imaginable libraries, but still it does not work.

I might make this post longer, adding some details, but I bet I'm not the first linux user that gets in trouble configuring an opensource development environment on Windows.

Does anybody know how to "import" a working makefile into eclipse project settings, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved by copying the libraries list from `make` console output:

`g++ -o bombs.exe bombs_bombs.o bombs_bombs1.o bombs_game.o bombs_bombs_rc.o    -L/c/wxWidgets-3.1.1/lib -mwindows    -lwx_mswu_core-3.1  -lwx_baseu-3.1        -lpng -lz -ljpeg -ltiff -llzma  -lwxregexu-3.1  -lz -lrpcrt4 -loleaut32 -lole32 -luuid -luxtheme -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lgdi32 -loleacc  -lz -lrpcrt4 -loleaut32 -lole32 -luuid -luxtheme -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lgdi32 -loleacc`

Some of them are not explicitly written in the `makefile`, or I was unable to find them.

Answer (score 1):

You should just copy the full libraries list from `makefile.gcc` to the link options in the IDE, i.e. `-lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lwininet -loleacc -luxtheme` (see `build/msw/makefile.gcc`).

Comment: ...And after those MSW libs, add the wx-libs needed to your project.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, very good hints, but something was still missing.